# How can I configure the TeamCity Inspections (.NET) Runner for multiple solutions

Tags: .net, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I am using TeamCity Professional 7.0.2 (build 21349) and have added the *Inspections (.NET)* runner (Runner for gathering JetBrains ReSharper inspection results) as a build step.

The Solution file path is a mandatory field and [according to the current documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Inspections+%28.NET%29), this is the "Path to .sln file. Specified path should be relative to the checkout directory."

I have multiple solutions (over 20) so tried `*.sln` but it failed (which I guess is to be expected).

```
[16:33:17]Step 5/5: ReSharper Inspections (Inspections (.NET)) (1m:17s)
[16:34:32][Step 5/5] Invalid char '*' in path *.sln
[16:34:34][Step 5/5] Inspections (.NET) execution failure
[16:34:34][Step 5/5] Step ReSharper Inspections (Inspections (.NET)) failed
```

I was wondering if anyone knew of a workaround for this?

I've posted a [feature request on the support site](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21113).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from JetBrains:

> The only workaround now is to define several build steps, one per each
>   solution.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21113